# What is the path of a UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage

I am working with the `UIImage` class initializer `init(contentsOfFile:)`. But how should I specify the exact path. For example, I have a picture called "Picture" saved in desktop of my mac, and then how can I use this picture? Just `"Picture.png"` or `"/Users/Username/Desktop/Picture.png"`, or I have to save that picture in a specific folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Add the file "picture.png" to your project.
2. Use imageNamed method of UIImage class to reference the file.

Like (for obj-c):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture"];
```

or (for swift):

```
let image = UIImage(named:"picture")
```

That should do.